# Android License Check Fails WAY too much, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I have an Android app that uses the Google Licensing service and I get regular emails from about 5% of new users complaining that the license check is failing. It is starting to affect my sales. What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
this.licenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();

String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

// Construct the LicenseChecker with a Policy.
this.licenseChecker = new LicenseChecker(
    this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
            new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)), 
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  // Your public licensing key.
    );

this.checkLicense();




private void checkLicense() {
    this.licenseChecker.checkAccess(this.licenseCheckerCallback);
}


private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {

    public void allow() {
        // Don't do anything, let the user work in peace.
    }

    public void dontAllow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
        // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
        // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
        // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
        // restricted set of features.
        // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
        showDialog(DIALOG_NO_LICENSE_ID);
        MyActivity.this.dialogIdCurrentlyShown = DIALOG_NO_LICENSE_ID;
    }

    public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
        // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
        // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
        MyActivity.this.applicationErrorMessageForDialog = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
        showDialog(DIALOG_APPLICATION_ERROR_ID);
        MyActivity.this.dialogIdCurrentlyShown = DIALOG_APPLICATION_ERROR_ID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't doing anything wrong. I am having the same problem, and other people too. And there's not much you could do, but still:

1. Open a support ticket with Google telling them the performance of LVL suboptimal and is affecting legitimate users.
2. Add a 'Retry' button to your 'Not licensed' dialog. Sometimes it's just a transient network failure which results in licensing failure.
3. Consider leaving Google's support email in our dialog, or adding other means for a user to convey the problem to its source.
4. And the only effective option, probably: manually increase the value of `GT` timestamp received from the licensing service before storing it in cache, if the response is for a permanent purchase. Check the difference between the `GT` timestamp and the `VT` timestamp - if it is large enough (a week), add another month or even a year to `GT`. The idea is that once the user has passed the refund period, you can make his/her license semi-permanent or completely permanent on his/her device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an email for Google support. Can you help me? I think that's a great idea.

Comment: They don't provide support. However, they do have a clear policy, read at the bottom of the http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113477 page. So you can provide an html link instead on an email.